# Hooking a function I don't know the parameters to

Tags: c, winapi, dll, hook

Lets say there is a DLL `A.DLL` with a known entry point `DoStuff` that I have in some way hooked out with my own DLL `fakeA.dll` such that the system is calling my `DoStuff` instead. How do I write such a function such that it can then call the same entry point of the hooked DLL (`A.DLL`) without knowing the arguments of the function? I.e. My function in `fakeA.DLL` would look something like

```
LONG DoStuff(
// don't know what to put here
)
{
    FARPROC pfnHooked;
    HINSTANCE hHooked;
    LONG lRet;

    // get hooked library and desired function

    hHooked = LoadLibrary("A.DLL");
    pfnHooked = GetProcAddress(hHooked, "DoStuff");

    // how do I call the desired function without knowing the parameters?

    lRet = pfnHooked( ??? );

    return lRet;
}
```

My current thinking is that the arguments are on the stack so I'm guessing I would have to have a sufficiently large stack variable (a big ass `struct` for example) to capture whatever the arguments are and then just pass it along to `pfnHooked`? I.e.

```
// actual arg stack limit is >1MB but we'll assume 1024 bytes is sufficient
typedef struct { char unknownData[1024]; } ARBITARY_ARG; 

ARBITARY_ARG DoStuff(ARBITARY_ARG args){
    ARBITARY_ARG aRet;
    ...
    aRet = pfnHooked(args);

    return aRet;
}
```

Would this work? If so, is there a better way?

---

UPDATE: After some rudimentary (and non-conclusive) testing passing in the arbitrary block as arguments DOES work (which is not surprising, as the program will just read what it needs off the stack). However collecting the return value is harder as if it's too large it can cause an access violation. Setting the arbitrary return size to 8 bytes (or maybe 4 for x86) may be a solution to most cases (including void returns) however that's still guesswork. If I had some way of knowing the return type from the DLL (not necessarily at runtime) that would be grand.

Comment: 1/ You can't do this in C. 2/ C knows nothing about "DLL". You're referring to machine code. 3/ C knows nothing about `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress`, etc. You're referring to win32-specific machine code. 4/ You can't do this in C.

Comment: @Seb Of course C knows nothing about DLL. This question was marked winapi. C does know function addresses though, which is what winapi is fetching here. The question is whether there is a technique to do this for a DLL.

Comment: There is no language technique that will allow you to sensibly handle arguments you don't know *what they mean*. Even if you made your method work (which is pretty likely, simple handle no arguments at all and return something sensible that doesn't look like an error code), you have not achieved anything better than what you could achieve with a good debugger. Your ultimate goal is *understand the arguments* - And you can achieve that with a debugger much better.

Comment: @tofro I'm not actually trying to understand the arguments (where did I say that?), I just want to hook the function in this way. What I want is described in the title of this question

Comment: A simple forwarder doesn't need to do anything in particular. Simply mark your fake function as [__declspec(naked)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs.aspx), and jump to the real implementation from there. Your fake function doesn't need to declare any parameters. Caveats: You cannot do anything inside your function, because arguments may have been passed in registers. There's also no way to jump to a function (vs. calling it) in C. That'd require inline assembly, which isn't ubiquitously supported.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the insight, but I need to be able to call the hooked function. So yes, assembly may be the only option, which kinda means I just need to do more traditional hooking, which I have no experience in unfortunately...

Comment: The detail that you need to be able to call the hooked function (presumably because you need its return value) is not clear from the question.

Comment: Looks very badly as some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are the possible cases for `DoStuff`? What does your program really want to achieve?

Comment: @IInspectable First paragraph is meant to mean that, I'll make it clearer.

Answer (score 5):

This should be a comment but the meta answer is yes you can hook the function without knowing the calling convention and arguments, on an x64/x86 platform. Can it be purely done in C? No, it also needs a good deal of understanding of various calling convention and Assembly programming. The hooking framework will have some of it's bits written in Assembly.

Most hooking framework inherently do that by creating a trampoline that redirects the execution flow from the called function's preamble to stub code that is generally independent of the function it is hooking. In user mode you're guaranteed stack to be always present so you can push your own local variables too on the same stack as long as you can pop them and restore the stack to it's original state.

You don't really need to copy the existing arguments to your own stack variable. You can just inspect the stack, definitely read a bit about calling convention and how stacks are constructed on different architectures for various types of invocation in assembly before you attempt anything.

Answer (score 2):

yes, this is possible do generic hooking 100% correct - one common for multiple functions with different arguments count and calling conventions. for both *x86/x64 (amd64)* platforms.

but for this need use little **asm** stubs - of course it will be different for *x86/x64* - but it will be very small - several lines of code only - 2 small stub procedures - one for filter pre-call and one for post-call. but most code implementation (95%+) will be platform independent and in **c++** (of course this possible do and on **c** but compare **c++** - **c** source code will be larger, ugly and harder to implement)

in my solution need allocate small executable blocks of code for every hooking api (one block per hooked api). in this block - store function name, original address (or to where transfer control after pre-call - this is depended from hooking method) and one relative **call** instruction to common asm pre-call stub. magic of this **call** not only that it transfer control to common stub, but that return address in stack will be point to block itself (ok , with  some offset, but if we will use **c++** and inheritance - it will be exactly point to some base class, from which we derive our executable block class). as result in common precall stub we will be have information - which api call we hook here and then pass this info to **c++** common handler.

one note, because in *x64* relative call can be only in range `[rip-0x80000000, rip+0x7fffffff]` need declare (allocate) this code blocks inside our *PE* in separate *bss* section and mark this section as *RWE*. we can not simply use *VirtualAlloc* for allocate storage, because returned address can be too far from our common precall stub.

in common **asm** precall stub code must save *rcx,rdx,r8,r9* registers for *x64* (this is absolute mandatory) and *ecx,edx* registers for x86. this is need for case if function use *__fastcall* calling conventions. however windows api for example almost not using *__fastcall* - only several *__fastcall* functions exist from thousands of win api (for ensure this and found this functions - go to *LIB* folder and search for `__imp_@` string (this is *__fastcall* common prefix) and then call **c++** common handler, which must return address of original function(to where transfer control) to stub. stub restore *rcx,rdx,r8,r9* (or *ecx,edx*) registers and **jump** (but not **call** !) to this address

if we want filter only pre-call this is all what we need. however in most case need filter (hook) and post-call - for view/modify function return value and *out* parameters. and this is also possible do, but need little more coding.

for hook post-call obviously we must replace the return address for hooked api. but on what we must change return address ? and where save original return address ? for this we can not use global variable. even can not use thread local (`__declspec( thread )` or `thread_local`) because call can be reqursive. can not use volatile register (because it changed during api call) and can not use non-volatile register - because in this case we will be save it,for restore later - but got some question - where ?

only one (and nice) solution here - allocate small block of executable memory (*RWE*) which containing one relative **call** instruction to common post-call asm stub. and some data - saved original return address, function parameters(for check out parameters in post handler) and function name

here again, some issuer for x64 - this block must be not too far from common post stub (+/- 2GB) - so the best also allocate this stubs in separate *.bss* section (with the pre-call stubs).

how many need this ret-stubs ? one per api call (if we want control post call). so not more than api calls active at any time. usually say 256 pre-allocated blocks - more than enough. and even if we fail allocate this block in pre-call - we only not control it post call, but not crash. and we can not for all hooked api want control post-call but only for some.

for very fast and interlocked alloc/free this blocks - need build stack semantic over it. allocate by interlocked pop and free by interlocked push. and pre initialize (call instruction) this blocks at begin (while push all it to stack, for not reinitialize it every time in pre-call)

common post-call stub in **asm** is very simply - here we not need save any registers. we simply call *c++* post handler with address of block (we pop it from stack - result of **call** instruction **from** block) and with original return value (*rax* or *eax*). strictly said - api function can return pair *rax+rdx* or *eax+edx* but 99.9%+ of windows api return value in single register and i assume that we will be hooking only this api. however if want, can little adjust code for handle this too (simply in most case this not need)

**c++** post call handler restore original return address (by using `_AddressOfReturnAddress()`), can log call and/or modify out parameters and finally return to.. original caller of api. what our handler return - this and will be final return value of api call. usually we mast return original value.

**c++** code

```
#if 0 
#define __ASM_FUNCTION __pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__" proc\r\n" __FUNCDNAME__ " endp"))
#define _ASM_FUNCTION {__ASM_FUNCTION;}
#define ASM_FUNCTION {__ASM_FUNCTION;return 0;}
#define CPP_FUNCTION __pragma(message("extern " __FUNCDNAME__ " : PROC ; "  __FUNCTION__))
#else
#define _ASM_FUNCTION
#define ASM_FUNCTION
#define CPP_FUNCTION
#endif

class CODE_STUB
{
#ifdef _WIN64
    PVOID pad;
#endif
    union
    {
        DWORD code;
        struct  
        {
            BYTE cc[3];
            BYTE call;
        };
    };
    int offset;

public:

    void Init(PVOID stub)
    {
        // int3; int3; int3; call stub
        code = 0xe8cccccc;
        offset = RtlPointerToOffset(&offset + 1, stub);

        C_ASSERT(sizeof(CODE_STUB) == RTL_SIZEOF_THROUGH_FIELD(CODE_STUB, offset));
    }

    PVOID Function()
    {
        return &call;
    }

    // implemented in .asm
    static void __cdecl retstub()  _ASM_FUNCTION;
    static void __cdecl callstub() _ASM_FUNCTION;
};

struct FUNC_INFO
{
    PVOID OriginalFunc;
    PCSTR Name;

    void* __fastcall OnCall(void** stack);
};

struct CALL_FUNC : CODE_STUB, FUNC_INFO
{
};  

C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(CALL_FUNC,OriginalFunc) == sizeof(CODE_STUB));

struct RET_INFO 
{
    union
    {
        struct  
        {
            PCSTR Name;
            PVOID params[7];
        };

        SLIST_ENTRY Entry;
    };

    INT_PTR __fastcall OnCall(INT_PTR r);
};

struct RET_FUNC : CODE_STUB, RET_INFO 
{
};

C_ASSERT(FIELD_OFFSET(RET_FUNC, Entry) == sizeof(CODE_STUB));

#pragma bss_seg(".HOOKS")

RET_FUNC g_rf[1024];//max call count
CALL_FUNC g_cf[16];//max hooks count

#pragma bss_seg() 

#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.HOOKS,RWE")

class RET_FUNC_Manager 
{
    SLIST_HEADER _head;

public:

    RET_FUNC_Manager()
    {
        PSLIST_HEADER head = &_head;

        InitializeSListHead(head);

        RET_FUNC* p = g_rf;
        DWORD n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(g_rf);

        do 
        {
            p->Init(CODE_STUB::retstub);
            InterlockedPushEntrySList(head, &p++->Entry);
        } while (--n);
    }

    RET_FUNC* alloc()
    {
        return static_cast<RET_FUNC*>(CONTAINING_RECORD(InterlockedPopEntrySList(&_head), RET_INFO, Entry));
    }

    void free(RET_INFO* p)
    {
        InterlockedPushEntrySList(&_head, &p->Entry);
    }
} g_rfm;

void* __fastcall FUNC_INFO::OnCall(void** stack)
{
    CPP_FUNCTION;

    // in case __fastcall function in x86 - param#1 at stack[-1] and param#2 at stack[-2]

    // this need for filter post call only
    if (RET_FUNC* p = g_rfm.alloc())
    {
        p->Name = Name;
        memcpy(p->params, stack, sizeof(p->params));
        *stack = p->Function();
    }

    return OriginalFunc;
}

INT_PTR __fastcall RET_INFO::OnCall(INT_PTR r)
{
    CPP_FUNCTION;

    *(void**)_AddressOfReturnAddress() = *params;

    PCSTR name = Name;
    char buf[8];
    if (IS_INTRESOURCE(name))
    {
        sprintf(buf, "#%04x", (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)name), name = buf;
    }

    DbgPrint("%p %s(%p, %p, %p ..)=%p\r\n", *params, name, params[1], params[2], params[3], r);
    g_rfm.free(this);
    return r;
}

struct DLL_TO_HOOK 
{
    PCWSTR szDllName;
    PCSTR szFuncNames[];
};

void DoHook(DLL_TO_HOOK** pp)
{
    PCSTR* ppsz, psz;
    DLL_TO_HOOK *p;
    ULONG n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(g_cf);

    CALL_FUNC* pcf = g_cf;

    while (p = *pp++)
    {
        if (HMODULE hmod = LoadLibraryW(p->szDllName))
        {
            ppsz = p->szFuncNames;

            while (psz = *ppsz++)
            {
                if (pcf->OriginalFunc = GetProcAddress(hmod, psz))
                {
                    pcf->Name = psz;
                    pcf->Init(CODE_STUB::callstub);

                    // do hook: pcf->OriginalFunc -> pcf->Function() - code for this skiped
                    DbgPrint("hook: (%p) <- (%p)%s\n", pcf->Function(), pcf->OriginalFunc, psz);

                    if (!--n)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    pcf++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**asm x64** code:

```
extern ?OnCall@FUNC_INFO@@QEAAPEAXPEAPEAX@Z : PROC ; FUNC_INFO::OnCall
extern ?OnCall@RET_INFO@@QEAA_J_J@Z : PROC ; RET_INFO::OnCall

?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ proc
    pop rcx
    mov rdx,rax
    call ?OnCall@RET_INFO@@QEAA_J_J@Z
?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ endp

?callstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ proc
    mov [rsp+10h],rcx
    mov [rsp+18h],rdx
    mov [rsp+20h],r8
    mov [rsp+28h],r9
    pop rcx
    mov rdx,rsp
    sub rsp,18h
    call ?OnCall@FUNC_INFO@@QEAAPEAXPEAPEAX@Z
    add rsp,18h
    mov rcx,[rsp+8]
    mov rdx,[rsp+10h]
    mov r8,[rsp+18h]
    mov r9,[rsp+20h]
    jmp rax
?callstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ endp
```

**asm x86 code**

```
extern ?OnCall@FUNC_INFO@@QAIPAXPAPAX@Z : PROC ; FUNC_INFO::OnCall
extern ?OnCall@RET_INFO@@QAIHH@Z : PROC ; RET_INFO::OnCall

?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ proc
    pop ecx
    mov edx,eax
    call ?OnCall@RET_INFO@@QAIHH@Z
?retstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ endp

?callstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ proc
    xchg [esp],ecx
    push edx
    lea edx,[esp + 8]
    call ?OnCall@FUNC_INFO@@QAIPAXPAPAX@Z
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    jmp eax
?callstub@CODE_STUB@@SAXXZ endp
```

you can ask from where i know this decorated names like `?OnCall@FUNC_INFO@@QAIPAXPAPAX@Z` ? look for very begin of **c++** code - for several macros - and first time compile with `#if 1` and look in output window. hope you understand (and you will be probably need use this names, but not my names - decoration can be different)

and how call `void DoHook(DLL_TO_HOOK** pp)` ? like that:

```
DLL_TO_HOOK dth_kernel32 = { L"kernel32", { "VirtualAlloc", "VirtualFree", "HeapAlloc", 0 } };
DLL_TO_HOOK dth_ntdll = { L"ntdll", { "NtOpenEvent", 0 } };

DLL_TO_HOOK* ghd[] = { &dth_ntdll, &dth_kernel32, 0 };
DoHook(ghd);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say there is a DLL `A.DLL` with a known entry point `DoStuff`

If the entry point `DoStuff` is *known* it ought to be documented somewhere, at the very least in some C header file. So a possible approach might be to parse that header to get its signature (i.e. the C declaration of `DoStuff`). Maybe you could fill some database with the signature of all functions declared in all system header files, etc... Or perhaps use debug information if you have it.

If you call some function (in C) and don't give all the required parameters, the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) & [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) will still be used, and these (missing) parameters get garbage values (if the calling convention defines that parameter to be passed in a register, the garbage inside that register; if the convention defines that parameter to be passed on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), the garbage inside that particular call stack slot). So you are likely to crash and surely have some [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which is *scary*, since your program might *seem* to work but still be very wrong).

However, look also into [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/). Once you know (at runtime) what to pass to some arbitrary function, you can construct a call to it passing the right number and types of arguments.

> My current thinking is that the arguments are on the stack

I think it is wrong (at least on many x86-64 systems). Some arguments are passed thru registers. Read about [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

> Would this work?

No, it won't work because some arguments are passed thru registers, and because the calling convention depends upon the signature of the called function (floating point values might be passed in different registers, or always on the stack; variadic functions have specific calling conventions; etc....)

BTW, some recent C [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) are able to do [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimizations, which might complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way of doing this because lot of things like calling conventions, pointer sizes etc matter when passing arguments. You will have to read the ABI for your platform and write an implementation, which I fear again won't be possible in C. You will need some inline assembly.

One simple way to do it would be (for a platform like X86_64) -

```
MyDoStuff:
    jmpq *__real_DoStuff
```

This hook does nothing but just calls the real function. If you want to do anything useful while hooking you will have to save restore some registers before the call (again what to save depends on the ABI)